# Insert Authorization Header field with kingfisher lib

Tags: ios, xcode, sdwebimage, kingfisher

I'm using Kingfisher to show image from url, but my endpoint requires a Authorization header.
How to use these kind of url with Kingfisher or SDWebImage in iOS?

Answer (score 21):

With Kingfisher you need to make a request modifier (of type `AnyModifier`) and pass it as a parameter in the `options` part of the `.kf.setImage` method, and then use the trailing closure to actually set the image.

Example:

```
import Kingfisher

let modifier = AnyModifier { request in
    var r = request
    // replace "Access-Token" with the field name you need, it's just an example
    r.setValue(<YOUR_TOKEN>, forHTTPHeaderField: "Access-Token")
    return r
}

let url = URL(string: <YOUR_URL>)

let iView = <YOUR_IMAGEVIEW>

iView.kf.setImage(with: url, options: [.requestModifier(modifier)]) { (image, error, type, url) in
    if error == nil && image != nil {
        // here the downloaded image is cached, now you need to set it to the imageView
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            iView.image = image
        }
    } else {
        // handle the failure
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 17):

**Centralised** and **reliable** way to pass custom headers to all the image requests.

No option required for all *setImage(with:,option:)* call

```
class TokenPlugin: ImageDownloadRequestModifier {
    let token:String

    init(token:String) {
        self.token = token
    }

    func modified(for request: URLRequest) -> URLRequest? {
        var request = request
        request.addValue(token, forHTTPHeaderField: "token")
        return request
    }
}
```

**Config**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    KingfisherManager.shared.defaultOptions = [.requestModifier(TokenPlugin(token:"abcdef123456"))]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    let modifier = AnyModifier { request in
        var req = request
        req.addValue("your_token", forHTTPHeaderField: "authorization")
        return req
    }
    
    
    KingfisherManager.shared.defaultOptions += [
        .requestModifier(modifier)
    ]}
```

**Swift 5 + Kingfisher 7.1.2 tested on Xcode 13.2.1**

Answer (score 0):

> With Kingfisher you need to make a request modifier (of type
> AnyModifier) and pass it as a parameter in the options part of the
> .kf.setImage method, and then use the trailing closure to actually set
> the image.

-> Because I use Firebase, I use **getFirebaseToken()**

```
extension UIImageView {
    
    func loadImage(from url: URL, placeHolderImage: UIImage? = nil) {
        let modifier = AnyModifier { request in
            var r = request
            if let firebaseToken = AccountManager.shared.getFirebaseToken() {
                r.setValue("Bearer \(firebaseToken)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
            }
            return r
        }
        self.kf.setImage(with: url, placeholder: placeHolderImage, options: [.requestModifier(modifier), .forceRefresh])
    }
}
```